# Async method for the home page to load faster

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I am building an application and after deploying it, I tested it with several tools available on the internet, one of them being http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

After the test, it told me that the server response is very slow. I noticed that when i opened my home page, it took a while to open the page.

here is my Index method :

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IndexModel indexModel = new IndexModel();

        indexModel.news = db.News.ToList().OrderByDescending(News => News.Date);
        indexModel.paper = db.Papers.ToList().OrderByDescending(Paper => Paper.Date);

        return View(indexModel);
    }
```

I want to make this into an async method. Will that make it faster? Or do you have other solutions?

Comment: Do your `News` and `Papers` tables have many records in? As you're loading them **all** into memory. Consider paging or some other mechanism so you don't have to load so much data.

Comment: they don't have a lot of records now, but they will have

Answer (score 0):

Yes, async will speed up this since they are tasks that can be performed in parallell. But you have to make each call to get your records async, not just one async method with both calls i it. In this case though, I'm assuming that you are accessing both `News` and `Paper` from the same data source (i.e. database), and therefor it's not certain how big of a gain you get since you are putting load on your database server.

I'd suggest that you start by reading up on [asynchronous programming on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx).

However, as mentioned by mattytommo, you should definitely limit your queries, otherwise you can be DoS-attacked intentionally (and unintentionally by Google bot, etc.)

Comment: how can i make the tasks async ? can you help me with a piece of code ?

Answer (score 0):

`indexModel` seems very static oject to me. I mean It doesn't have any dependency on any parameter. you are serving all records for all requests.

Why don't you save those records in `ApplicationContext` & go to database only when it is missing from `ApplicationContext`?

I bet that will give you 50% boost in yours speed tests.

### edit

Bundle all your css files and javascript files into single files and minify them.
This is help you make the first load faster. This will decrease the number of request browser sends making it load faster.

### edit

modify your code as follows

```
indexModel.news = db.News.OrderByDescending(News => News.Date).ToList();
indexModel.paper = db.Papers.OrderByDescending(Paper => Paper.Date).ToList();
```

this will sort it in database reducing c# processing hence making further fast.

Comment: after a cache of the page is done, the page is fast. the first load takes a lot of time. that's what i want to speed up.